# length(x) is positive but error keeps showing up when using sapply?

Tags: r

My orignal data looks something like this:

```
Date    EUR HIGH    EUR LOW EUR CLOSE   JPY CURNCY  JPY LOW JPY CLOSE   GBP  CURNCY  GBP CURNCY  GBP CURNCY
8/30/2016   1.12    1.12    1.12    102.56  101.76  102.50  1.31    1.31    1.31
8/29/2016   1.12    1.12    1.12    102.39  101.84  101.92  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/28/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/27/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/26/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/25/2016   1.13    1.13    1.13    100.62  100.30  100.53  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/24/2016   1.13    1.12    1.13    100.61  100.10  100.45  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/23/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.39  99.94   100.24  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/22/2016   1.13    1.13    1.13    100.93  100.21  100.33  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/21/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/20/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/19/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
```

I then used this code to tidy it up / sort it by individual currency:

```
cur<-c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 
      'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 
      'KRW', 'MYR', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'THB')
i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(y,names(x)), USE.NAMES = F)
MergedData <- apply(i,2, function(i) x[c(1,i)] )
```

Recently I added two more columns per currency -- last price and open. So now I have:

Date        EUR OPEN   EUR HIGH    EUR LOW   EUR CLOSE  EEUR LAST
8/30/2016   1.12         1.12    1.12           1.12    1.12

And now the code doesn't work anymore, even after changing it to:

```
cur<-c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 
      'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 
      'KRW', 'MYR', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'THB')
i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(y,names(x)), USE.NAMES = F)
MergedData <- apply(i,4, function(i) x[c(1,i)] )
```

And an error comes up saying dim(x) must have a positive length, but dim(x) returns

> dim(x)
>   [1] 243 146

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I suspect the error appears after `apply` and is because the structure of `i` is not a matrix, but a list. That is, `dim(i)` is NULL and `length(dim(i))` is 0.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but str(x) returns a data frame.  dim(x) returns [1] 243 146

Comment: You may have misread my comment, I'm referring to `i`, the object returned by `sapply(cur, function(y) grep(y,names(x)), USE.NAMES = F)`.

Comment: Oh how embarrassing, You are right, dim(i) is a list. It seems like it's fixable by replacing apply with sapply(i, function(i) x[c(1,i)] ), Thanks!